# How to bypass iOS Universal Link feature?

Tags: ios, asp.net, redirect, ios-universal-links

I've a ASP.NET website that runs authentication through Yammer (oauth2). So, during the process, the app redirects to `yammer.com/authenticate...`

The problem is that on iOS devices that have the Yammer app installed, the authenticate URL opens up in the app, and then the whole website shows "inside" the Yammer app which is causing some issues.

I need to override the Universal Link feature so everything runs inside Safari and the Yammer app doens't get involved.

I've read that "masking" the redirect URL (via a URL shortener for example) avoids the engagement of Universal Link feature and carry everything on Safari, is that correct?

Any other workarounds on the website side? (asking people to disable Universal Linking is not an option).

Answer (score 1):

You're best option is to wrap the URL with a different domain that opens the `yammer` domain via javascript.

```
window.open("yammer.com/authenticate...","_self")
```

Apple will only open the app when a user **taps** the universal link meaning that you cannot programmatically open the app via javascript redirect. I believe a 301 redirect will trigger a Universal Link app open though, which seems to be your case. Some link shorteners may open via 301 redirects and some may use Javascript so I'd try multiple ones and see. It seems like Apple is always changing their mind on this behavior so stay on your toes ;)

Comment: I've tried  `window.location.href` and `window.location.replace()` and both trigger Universal Link app... I'll try `window.open()`.

Comment: Ah interesting. It may be the case that Apple changed this. Please report back with your findings. @emzero